# Array to a range where the range has missed columns

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to output an array to a range, however I want the range to be made up of several parts. My example code is below with the expected output.

```
Sub test()

 a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

 Range("A2:B2,D2:F2") = a

End Sub
```

Output I Get:

A-B-C-D-E-F

1-2---1-2-3

Output I Want:

A-B-C-D-E-F

1-2---3-4-5

How do I achieve the output I need from the array? As you can see the output skips column C correctly but starts to output the array from the start again and not continue as I expected.

Comment: Fyi Posted a late extension on the valid answers of Nov 3 allowing to automate the input of partial arrays. @TAS1987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, sadly.  You'll need to write code to write to a discontinuous `Range` the way you want.  This has been discussed before on another site: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/filling-a-non-contiguous-range-with-an-array-with-vba.763467/

This won't be valid for all situations of course, but if you know the sizes of the discontinuous ranges beforehand, you could store your info in multiple arrays that are appropriately sized, and then write to each range the data in the respective array.  This way, you avoid the problem entirely.

If that's not possible, I would create a `Sub` that takes an array and all of the ranges as inputs, splits the array into as many appropriately-sized arrays as needed, and then write each of those arrays to the respective ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it does exactly what is expected.
If you want to fill non-continous ranges you need to do it with each area:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Area1 As Variant
    Area1 = Array(1, 2)
    Range("A2:B2") = Area1

    Dim Area2 As Variant
    Area2 = Array(3, 4, 5)

    Range("D2:F2") = Area2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Late extension to the valid answers above allowing to *automate* the assignment of **partial array values** to a non-contiguous range; as said it is not possible to do this by a single assignment:

**a) Automate assigning partial values**

```
Sub testSlice()
'1. Define array values
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
'2. Assign sliced array values to each range area
    With Sheet1.Range("A2:B2,D2:F2")              ' non contiguous range
        Dim i As Long, col As Long
        For i = 1 To .Areas.Count                 ' loop through each area
            Dim cols As Long: cols = .Areas(i).Columns.Count
            'Assign partial array
            .Areas(i) = Slice(arr, col + 1, cols) ' << aux. function
            col = col + cols                      ' provide for next col
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Function Slice()**

Slices the given array values into partial arrays according to the individual areas via `Application.Index()`:

```
Function Slice(arr, ByVal startCol As Long, ByVal columnCount As Long)
'Purp: slice "flat" 1-dim array
'Note: Sequence function assumes vers. MS 365 !!
'      (Index function returns 1-based values)
    Slice = Application.Index(arr, Application.Sequence(1, columnCount, startCol))
End Function
```

Instead of `Sequence()` you can use a column evaluation for prior versions:

```
    Function Slice(arr, ByVal startCol As Long, ByVal columnCount As Long)
    'Purp: slice "flat" 1-dim array for non-365 versions
        Slice = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("Row(" & startCol & ":" & (startCol + columnCount - 1) & ")"))
        Slice = Application.Transpose(Slice)
    End Function
```

---

**b) Alternative with single cell assignments**

```
Sub test2()
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

'non contiguous range (assumes a one-row range as in OP!)
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:B2,D2:F2")

Dim cell As Range, i As Long
For Each cell In rng
    cell = arr(i)   ' assign array vals to cell
    i = i + 1       ' increment 0-based arr index
Next cell

End Sub
```